# Change button style after pressed - CSS

Tags: css, button, themes, zend-framework

I'm using Zend Framework and I have a form input button with a style that I defined.
I need to replace the main data-theme once the button gets pressed.

I have in mind something like this:

```
$this->form->go->setAttrib("onclick", "this.data-theme='new_theme'");
```

.. but is not working.

any ideas??
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends if you mean 'on press' or 'after'; if on press, then the `:active` psuedoclass (as Simone states) is correct; if you want the different style to be persistent after you've clicked the button, then the `:visited` psuedoclass should work (although having said this, I'm not sure if `:visited` is only valid for `a href` links; if so, you could style a link to look like a button, which is fairly common)

Comment: hi! I don't have much choice I have this button to submit a form and I need to change the data-theme of the button after it gets pressed. for example from data-theme=a to data-theme=b

Comment: I don't know too much about Zend - try the `:visited` psuedoclass and let us know if that doesn't work...

Comment: Seems like only apply to a href though. I still failed to configure input[type="button"]

Answer (score 0):

You could just declare the new style in your stylesheet, with the `:active` pseudoclass.

Should be something like

```
input[type=button]:active {
    /* type here your rules, i.e. background-color:red; */ 
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks but I need to change the style of the button once it get's pressed

Comment: If I understood well, you could declare a `.pressed` class (or the name you want) that defines the new style for the button. Then your button will look like `<input type=button class=pressed>`